# How to add dummy variables for countries in time series data

Tags: time-series, logistic, categorical-encoding

I am running a binary logit regression. However, my independent variables consists of quantitative and dummy variables. Some of them are type of loan (5 types), loan purpose (5 types) and countries (15 countries).
I made n-1 variables for each dummy variables. That is I created binary dummy variables for 4 types of loan and the type with largest observation is left as the base category. Is this correct?

I tried same approach with countries. Is it correct to make 14 countries as binary variables?

When I ran the regression with this approach, I am getting quasi complete separation error for one of the loan type. Can someone advise?

Lastly, i also have one variable as risk score, it is either 5, 6, 7 or8 in all observations. Do i need to create a dummy variable for this? If yes, how?

I have added an image of the estimated equation. The last 14 variables represent each country

[image]

Comment: @richard hardy can you share your thoughts?

Comment: Contacting userb by the @-notation will only work for people who ave been active in the thread!

Comment: Please specify the program you are working in.

Comment: @Ben I use eviews software.

Comment: @Ben, although i used eviews to run the regression, I created my dummy variables via excel and uploaded the workfile on eviews